# How to setup server cron in specific minute

Tags: cron

I'm editing a crontab for a job that I want to run it every hour but at specific time like at 10:15AM, 11:15AM, 12:15PM so on. I'm not sure if this is possible though.

For every hour
0   *   *   *   *

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the minute to 15. So, you can use the following form:

```
15 * * * * <command>
```

[Cron manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) is worth a read, and there are plenty of tutorials out there that explain this even more clearly.